# How to reduce dependence caused by global variables in c program

Tags: c, multithreading, global-variables

I want to speed up the processing of a sequential C program using multi-threading. My problem is that my C program has a lot of global variables. They are read and written by the functions in my C program. Therefore, it is prevented to parallelize functions together by multithreading because it no longer holds the exact result compared to running sequence programs.

I using OpenMP to handle my C program. However, I wanna refactor my C program to react above purpose before use OpenMP

Here my example:

```
int a = 5 ; // global variable

funcA () {
    int b; 
    b = a + 5; // read a
}

funcB () {
    printf("%d\n", a); 
}
```

I don't wanna find the way to parallel complete `funcA` and `funcB` but I want reduce the dependency caused global variable (like variable `a` in above example).

Comment: Remove the global variable? I don't think there's an alternative.

Comment: In this case, you actually can run `funcA()` and `funcB()` in parallel, since they both only read from `a`. If someone writes to `a` at the same time, though, that's where you run into problems

Comment: yeah! I know. In case funcA reads variable a and funcB writes variable a, we have no way to parallelize function A and function B right? . I am looking for a solution that can minimize the dependence caused by global variables such as global localization. 
Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: It sounds like you are hoping for a trivial solution to a complex problem caused by poor decisions early on.  You're going to have to bite the bullet and do a lot of work; refactor your code to remove the global variables.

Comment: exactly!!! I have to deal with the mistake of the previous one. Is there any general way for refactoring code? Can you show me a specific case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way to do a complicated thing. It can seem difficult sometimes to design a code without global variables even when coding from zero. I your case, the problem is significantly more difficult.

There is not (and cannot be) a generic solution about how to minimize the number of global variables.

The only thing which can be done is:

- analyze the code base;
- understand the purpose of the global variables and how they are used;
- find a way to achieve the same behavior without using global variables.

Of course, it might be easier for some global variables to be dealt with than others. You may want to start with the former. Seeing success coming your way will help your morale during the task.

It might help you if you read about how to make code:

- tread safe;
- re-entrant.

Google can help you greatly on this.

Answer (score 1):

In general it is not an easy task to remove global variables.

You need to go on a case by case basis.

What you really need to do is to try to pass the variables required as function parameters rather than having them as globals.

In this example given, i cannot give any solution without looking at how the functions `funcA` and `funcB` are called. You should try to pass the variable `a` as a parameter to both the functions. You may need to go back up a few functions until you get to a common function which ultimately calls both functions.